# Finding only one value in nlargest dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'population': [59000000, 65000000, 434000,

                                  434000, 434000, 337000, 11300,

                                  11300, 11300],

                   'GDP': [1937894, 2583560 , 12011, 4520, 12128,

                           17036, 182, 38, 311],

                   'alpha-2': ["IT", "FR", "MT", "MV", "BN",

                               "IS", "NR", "TV", "AI"]},

                  index=["Italy", "France", "Malta",

                         "Maldives", "Brunei", "Iceland",

                         "Nauru", "Tuvalu", "Anguilla"])
```

And I would like to find 3 countries where the population is the highest. Normally I would use
`df.nlargest(3, 'population')`
And it would print me

```
France    65000000  2583560      FR
Italy     59000000  1937894      IT
Malta       434000    12011      MT
```

How to modify this code to show me only for example Countries or  alpha-2 not all the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since countries are your `index`, you can use the same code and just grab the index:

```
df.nlargest(3, 'population').index
```

Get's you:

```
Index(['France', 'Italy', 'Malta'], dtype='object')
```

If your 'countries' is your 2nd column, you can print it with `iloc` at index position 1 (python indexes start from 0, so 1 means essentially your 2nd column:

```
df.nlargest(3, 'population').iloc[:,1]

Out[60]: 
1    France
0     Italy
2     Malta
```

Or you can use `loc`:

```
df.nlargest(3, 'population').loc[:,'countries']

Out[64]: 
1    France
0     Italy
2     Malta
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: In largest dataset i have,countries are on the second column. How can i call it in python? Exactly like in the example where the population in the second. I would like to find 3 largest showing only population by GDP.

Comment: I tried df.nlargest(3, ['GDP']).df[df.columns[1]] but it is not this

Comment: Edited, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It works, the problem is that i don't get the iloc syntax well.

Comment: Have a read in the documentations for ```iloc``` and ```loc```. It is explained very clearly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.nlargest(3, 'population').index.values
```

Will print

```
['France' 'Italy' 'Malta']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the contents of the index...

```
df.nlargest(3, 'population').index.values
```

```
array(['France', 'Italy', 'Malta'], dtype=object)
```